# How to set customBinding to Transport Only Security?

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

How do you set a WCF customBinding to use only transport level security?

If it were a wsHttpBinding, it would be:

```
<security mode="Transport" />
```

The scenario is I am calling a Java SOAP service that uses transport-only security. No message signing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may be quite context specific, but I needed to use:

```
<security authenticationMode="MutualCertificateDuplex" />
```

There are many more "[authentication modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751836.aspx)" than there are "modes".

Answer (score 2):

I found that this custom binding ...

```xml
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="serviceSoap11">
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
          <httpsTransport />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint binding="customBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="serviceSoap11"
                contract="ServiceProxy.service"
                name="serviceSoap11"
                address="[URL]" />
    </client>
```

... is the equivalent of this basic http binding.

```xml
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="serviceSoap11">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="serviceSoap11"
                contract="ServiceProxy.service"
                name="serviceSoap11"
                address="[URL]" />
    </client>
```